# write to txt file in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I want to write random sorted data to a file. I'm using g++, but after running  the program there was no data saved to the file.

This is the code:

```
#include <string>
// basic file operations
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int ra;
    int pp = 0;
    ofstream myfile("fi21.txt");
    myfile.open("fi21.txt");

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ra = (rand()) + pp;
            pp = ra;

            std::string vv;
            vv = "1,";
            vv += i;
            vv += ",";
            vv += ra;
            vv += "\n";

            // myfile << vv;
            myfile.write(vv.c_str(), sizeof(vv));
        }
    }

    //  myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because you're opening the file twice. Once in the constructor, once by an explicit open. The second time, open() probably sets bad I/O state flag on the file stream object, so all your subsequent writes get quietly ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should/could look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int ra;
    int pp = 0;
    ofstream myfile("fi21.txt"); // This already opens the file, no need to call open

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ra = rand() + pp;
            pp = ra;

            // This will concatenate the strings and integers.
            // std::string::operator+= on the other hand, will convert
            // integers to chars. Is that what you want?
            myfile << "1," << i << "," << ra << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That superfluous call was the major problem, but also note that your attempt:

```
myfile.write(vv.c_str(), sizeof(vv));
```

has a mistake - `sizeof(vv)` is the number of bytes `std::string` takes on the stack, not how long it is. `std::string::length` or `std::string::size` is for that. Why to use the above at all, when you can `myfile << vv;`? I actually didn't even use `std::string` in the above code.